# How do I upload an image to the public:// directory?

Tags: 7, users, files, media

Is it possible to upload the picture and set it as user picture?

User picture can be set via `$user->picture = $file->fid; user_save($user);`but how do I upload the file from a URL to the `public://` directory?

Comment: Programmatically using URL (title), or using uploaded picture (question)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create the code for saving the image yourself, you could do

```
$response = drupal_http_request($url_image);

if ($response->code == 200){
  $file = file_save_data($response->data, 'public://' . 'foldername/' . $filename);
}
```

And in $file->fid you'll find the fid you need.

Comment: This will probably work, but if the user enters http://url-to-a-vey-lar.ge/file.png , that costs php  memory.

Comment: I'd like to know a better way, then. Always wanting to learn something new :)

Comment: looks good, but where are $filename from?

Comment: @m0d you can use curl (if installed) or even copy(newerphp versions only, requires some changes in php.ini that maybe insecure).

Comment: @Luciuz You set it. It includes the filename you want to use for saving the file.

Comment: @AyeshK You're right, maybe it's a better solution :)